# Unable to make html5 background video responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage that has a navbar on the left-hand side and the content area on the right. The content area has an html5 full-screen background video. Everything is perfect except the background video is not responsive. What I want are the video to be full screen and viewable in each and every screen size.

Sorry if this question has been posted before, but I didn't find a working solution from the other answers.

This is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
    <div class="main-content">                  
    <!-- background video -->
         <div class="videoContainer">
              <div class="overlay">
                   <video autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="images/backgrounds/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                   </video>
                   <div class="video-box-shadow"></div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-content{
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}

/*BACKGROUND VIDEO*/

.videoContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoContainer .video-box-shadow{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 8px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 8px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: inset 8px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: linear-gradient(320deg,
        rgba(0,0,0,1),
        rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        rgba(0,0,0,1));
}

.videoContainer .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}


.videoContainer .overlay video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `object-fit` and `object-position` CSS properties? They allow you to simply stretch the video the the size you want, then crop it the way you like it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 1):

Try using `object-fit` and `object-position` - these CSS properties allow any media to be scaled as if it were background images, using the actual container element as the wrapper.

```
.videoContainer .overlay video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
}
```

For example (with an image, but it works on any kind of visual media type):

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
img.fit {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="fit" />
```

You can see one is improperly stretched, the other looks correct, but slightly cut off. With this, you can stretch it and not worry about it full screen, with the video (or image, in my example) covering the entire space:

```css
html,
body,
img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

Comment: Tried it. But still not responsive. Maybe a code is blocking it?

Comment: What do you mean ‘not responsive’? Can you add relevant HTML in that case? Maybe you are missing a viewport meta tag or something... if this didn’t make your video responsive, maybe your site isnt responsive...

Answer (score 0):

you can use @media query in css for each screen or use bootstrap

Comment: If you cannot comment yet, earn the reputation to do so by giving good answers that explain how to do things and not mere suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing the **min-width** & **min-height** to plain **width** & **height** and adding **object-fit:cover** to your video element can accomplish what you want:

```
.videoContainer .overlay video {
    width: 100%;        /* Removed min- */
    height: 100%;       /* Removed min- */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    object-fit:cover;   /* Added this line */
}
```

I added a different video for testing which contains a watermark that allows you to see that it is centered.

[Here is a jsfiddle of the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/kyrsw30z/1/)

My testing displayed the video filling full height and width of screen while keeping it centered in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. The only apparent downfall to removing the **"min-"** from height/width dimensions is that Edge then seems to have trouble filling the screen with video. However, it is at least responsive, where before it was not. I am unable to test in Safari.